# Error: An exception occurred within a child process: ChecksumMismatchError: SHA256 mismatch

Tags: mongodb, installation, homebrew

I tried to install **mongoDB** using **homebrew**, but it's giving me this error :

```
Error: An exception occurred within a child process:
  ChecksumMismatchError: SHA256 mismatch
Expected: c7214ee7bda3cf9566e8776a8978706d9827c1b09017e17b66a5a4e0c0731e1f
  Actual: 6aa2e0c348e8abeec7931dced1f85d4
```

Answer (score 2):

Fix the sha256 value.

Please run `brew edit mongodb-community` and change `sha256 "c7214ee7bda3cf9566e8776a8978706d9827c1b09017e17b66a5a4e0c0731e1f"` to
`sha256 "6aa2e0c348e8abeec7931dced1f85d4bb161ef209c6af317fe530ea11bbac8f0"`

Answer (score 0):

With regards to Mongodb and Homebrew it's giving you and error because you have previously installed an older version of the formula. As per the `Mongodb docs` :

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-os-x/

To fix the `ChecksumMismatchError` Remove the downloaded .tgz archive.

```
brew untap mongodb/brew && brew tap mongodb/brew
```

Retap the formula with the updated version.

```
  brew install mongodb-community@4.4
```

view this case on stack overflow for all the steps you can take : https://stackoverflow.com/a/65551797/10468670