# Installing MongoDB with Homebrew

Tags: mongodb, macos, homebrew

I'm relatively new to MongoDB and am trying to install MongoDB on my Mac with Homebrew, but I'm getting the following error:

```
Error: No available formula with the name "mongodb" 
==> Searching for a previously deleted formula (in the last 
month)...
Warning: homebrew/core is shallow clone. To get complete history 
run:
  git -C "$(brew --repo homebrew/core)" fetch --unshallow

Error: No previously deleted formula found.
==> Searching for similarly named formulae...
Error: No similarly named formulae found.
==> Searching taps...
==> Searching taps on GitHub...
Error: No formulae found in taps.
```

I ran
`brew update`
Then
`brew install mongodb`

Comment: That’s not really an error, you’re trying to install a package (formula) that doesn’t exist. Have you searched for a solution? The [official docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-os-x/) have the correct command line.

Comment: Looks like `$ brew install mongodb-community@5.0` is not yet available via `brew`. Try  `$ brew install mongodb-community@4.4 `. Also make sure to specify the correct version to  `start ` and  `stop` mongodb.

Answer (score 459, accepted):

Formula `mongodb` has been removed from homebrew-core. Check [pr-43770](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/pull/43770) from homebrew-core

> To our users: if you came here because mongodb stopped working for you, we have removed it from the Homebrew core formulas since it was migrated to a **non open-source license**.

Fortunately, the team of mongodb is maintaining a custom Homebrew tap. You can uninstall the old mongodb and reinstall the new one from the new tap.

```sh
# If you still have the old mongodb installed from homebrew-core
brew services stop mongodb
brew uninstall homebrew/core/mongodb

# Use the migrated distribution from custom tap
brew tap mongodb/brew
brew install mongodb-community
brew services start mongodb-community
```

Check [mongodb/homebrew-brew](https://github.com/mongodb/homebrew-brew) for more info.

Comment: It only worked with `sudo brew services start mongodb-community`. Without sudo, my apps could never connect to a database because mongo defaulted to `/data/db` path regardless of its configuration.

Comment: @MattHagemann You may have messed things up. The default database location is `/usr/lobal/var/mongodb`, which could be confirmed by `brew cat mongodb-comunnity`. And don't use brew with sudo, which changes the owner of the package files and brings more trouble for you. I've explained once the bad of `sudo brew` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58487534/5101148).

Comment: @Simba Thanks for the warning. I've been able to fix the ownerships and start the service without `sudo`. It turned out `WiredTiger.turtle` (and others) inside dbPath were still under root ownership and should have been under my ID.

Comment: `brew install mongodb-community` is changed to `brew install mongodb-community@4.4`

Comment: Just upgraded macOS to 14.2 (23C64). Restarted ' brew services start mongodb-community' using '/mongodb-community/7.0.2/bin'. Now get Error: undefined method `plist_startup' for #<Formula mongodb-community (stable) /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/mongodb/homebrew-brew/Formula/mongodb-community.rb>

Comment: I got same error. "undefined method `plist_startup' for #<Formula mongodb-community (stable) /opt/homebrew/Library/Taps/mongodb/homebrew-brew/Formula/mongodb-community.rb>"

Answer (score 27):

With regards to `macOS Big Sur` and `Homebrew` the mongodb documentation states: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-os-x/

You should **install MongoDB 4.4 Community Edition** which supports macOS 10.13 or later, Therefor these steps will be helpful.

**SOLUTION 1:
If you have previously installed an older version of the formula, you may encounter a `ChecksumMismatchError` to fix that:**

Remove the downloaded .tgz archive.

```
brew untap mongodb/brew && brew tap mongodb/brew
```

Retap the formula.

```
  brew install mongodb-community@4.4
```

**SOLUTION 2:
If you haven't installed any version of the formula.**

1, Install the Xcode command-line tools and the Homebrew from https://brew.sh/#install

```
xcode-select --install
```

2, Tap the MongoDB Homebrew Tap:

```
brew tap mongodb/brew
```

3, Verify installation prerequisites in the macOS Terminal:

```
brew tap | grep mongodb
```

4, install MongoDB

```
brew install mongodb-community@4.4
```

Note: The installation includes:

• The mongod server,

• The mongos sharded cluster query router,

• The mongo shell

refer to this screenshot:

[image]

**Finally to run MongoDB (i.e. the mongod process) as a macOS service, issue the following:**

```
brew services start mongodb-community@4.4
```

screenshot:

[image]

Comment: it works, but doesn't work when I try to install mongodb-community@5.0

Comment: How do you access the mongo shell after installing?

Answer (score 16):

first install mongodb

```
brew tap mongodb/brew
```

Secondly install using this command. mangodb successfully installed

```
brew install mongodb-community@4.0
```

You will get the output

```
==> CaveatsTo have launchd start mongodb/brew/mongodb-community now and restart at login:
  brew services start mongodb/brew/mongodb-community
Or, if you don't want/need a background service you can just run:
  mongod --config /usr/local/etc/mongod.conf
==> Summary
  /usr/local/Cellar/mongodb-community/4.2.2: 21 files, 274.5MB, built in 2 minutes 46 seconds
brew services start mongodb/brew/mongodb-community
==> Successfully started `mongodb-community` (label: homebrew.mxcl.mongodb-commu
```

Answer (score 8):

Try this code in your terminal:

```
/usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
```

And then:

```
brew tap mongodb/brew
```

Finally:

```
brew install mongodb-community@4.0
```

Comment: You may also need to add the `mongo` executable to your path or add it as an alias, e.g. `export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/Cellar/mongodb-community@4.0/4.0.13/bin/` or `alias mongo=/usr/local/Cellar/mongodb-community@4.0/4.0.13/bin/mongo`

Comment: Then how to run the mongo deamon ? I mean the "mongod"-like command ??

Answer (score 2):

Just go for

```html
brew tap mongodb/brew
```

Answer (score 1):

```
~ % brew services run mongodb-community
/usr/local/opt/mongodb-community/homebrew.mxcl.mongodb-community.plist: service already loaded

Error: Failure while executing
/bin/launchctl bootstrap gui/501 /usr/local/opt/mongodb-community/homebrew.mxcl.mongodb-community.plist
exited with 17.
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

In MacOs Catalina doesn't work properly for me.

After the installation (https://zellwk.com/blog/install-mongodb/) i had to add permission to "/tmp/mongodb-27017.sock"

```
sudo chown -R `id -un` /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock
```

and the command "mongod" seems to ignore the config file (mongod.conf) in "/usr/local/etc" so i have to always launch it with the dbpath argument

```
mongod --dbpath /usr/local/var/mongodb
```

even if the same path is specified in the config file.

Also using "mongod" with configuration file doesn't work for me

```
mongod -f /usr/local/etc/mongod.conf
```

or

```
mongod --config /usr/local/etc/mongod.conf
```

I solved all these issues starting the mongodb via brew services. That worked well without issues and takes the parameters from the right configuration file.

```
brew services run mongodb-community
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want mongo dump and some others, consider this one:

```
brew tap mongodb/brew
brew install mongodb-database-tools
```

This gave me:

```
mongodump     mongoexport   mongofiles    mongoimport   mongorestore  mongostat     mongotop
```

under

```
/usr/local/Cellar/mongodb-database-tools/100.7.0/bin/
```

And symlinked to

```
/usr/local/bin
```

Comment: This worked for me on macOS Sonoma

Answer (score -2):

Homebrew at times won’t get installed in max while the OS is updated , like recently Max OS Ventura - it’s not supported , we can quickly install Mongo DB without homebrew just by using some commands in terminal , checkout the details here : https://medium.com/@pratheushcmohan/install-mongodb-in-mac-without-using-home-brew-23b2556ff930