# Trying to install mongoldb on MacOS

Tags: mongodb, macos, terminal, installation

I am trying to download mongodb via my terminal, but this is what I get as a response.

I already tried to reinstall brew.

Peters-MacBook-Pro:shopify-monitor main$ brew install mongodb
Error: No available formula with the name "mongodb" 
==> Searching for a previously deleted formula (in the last month)...
Warning: homebrew/core is shallow clone. To get complete history run:
  git -C "$(brew --repo homebrew/core)" fetch --unshallow

Error: No previously deleted formula found.
==> Searching for similarly named formulae...
Error: No similarly named formulae found.
==> Searching taps...
==> Searching taps on GitHub...
Error: No formulae found in taps.
Peters-MacBook-Pro:shopify-monitor main$

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/57856809/5101148

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Installing MongoDB with Homebrew](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57856809/installing-mongodb-with-homebrew)

Answer (score 2):

mongoDB is not open source anymore, and removed from Homebrew 。
You can refer:

- https://github.com/mongodb/homebrew-brew
- https://segmentfault.com/a/1190000020400235