# Homebrew MySQL 8.0.18 on macOS 10.15 Catalina won't run as service

Tags: mysql, homebrew, macos-catalina

Another macOS upgrade + another MySQL upgrade = another set of problems.

I can't seem to get MySQL 8.0.18 to run as a homebrew service on macOS 10.15 Catalina. Please show me the error of my ways.

**Here's what I did**:

1. brew install mysql
2. brew pin mysql
3. touch /tmp/mysql.sock
4. mysql.server start
5. unset TMPDIR
6. mysql_secure_installation
7. mysql.server stop
8. sudo brew services start mysql

**Here's what I expected**:

MySQL to run merrily along as a homebrew service as user root.

**Here's what happened**:

MySQL falls right over and dies, leaving a cryptic last statement in `/usr/local/var/mysql/[host.domain.com].err`:

```
"[ERROR] [MY-010123] [Server] Fatal error: Please read "Security" section of the manual to find out how to run mysqld as root!"
```

**Additional information**:

MySQL runs fine through subsequent reboots *so long as I launch it manually*:

```
sudo reboot now
ssh [servername.domain.com]
touch /tmp/mysql.sock
mysql.server start
```

Here's the `/usr/local/var/mysql/[servername.domain.com].err` file contents:

```
2019-10-20T18:02:14.6NZ mysqld_safe Logging to '/usr/local/var/mysql/moriarty.farces.com.err'.
2019-10-20T18:02:14.6NZ mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /usr/local/var/mysql
2019-10-20T18:02:14.670494Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/local/Cellar/mysql/8.0.18/bin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.18) starting as process 557
2019-10-20T18:02:14.685511Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010159] [Server] Setting lower_case_table_names=2 because file system for /usr/local/var/mysql/ is case insensitive
2019-10-20T18:02:15.617696Z 0 [System] [MY-010229] [Server] Starting crash recovery...
2019-10-20T18:02:15.626461Z 0 [System] [MY-010232] [Server] Crash recovery finished.
2019-10-20T18:02:15.795626Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010068] [Server] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.
2019-10-20T18:02:15.833541Z 0 [System] [MY-010931] [Server] /usr/local/Cellar/mysql/8.0.18/bin/mysqld: ready for connections. Version: '8.0.18'  socket: '/tmp/mysql.sock'  port: 3306  Homebrew.
2019-10-20T18:02:15.993739Z 0 [System] [MY-011323] [Server] X Plugin ready for connections. Socket: '/tmp/mysqlx.sock' bind-address: '127.0.0.1' port: 33060
```

After a reboot, when I try to run MySQL as a Homebrew service:

```
sudo reboot now
ssh [servername.domain.com]
sudo brew services start mysql
```

MySQL fails with the following error recorded in the `/usr/local/var/mysql/[servername.domain.com].err` file:

```
2019-10-20T18:44:13.780394Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010123] [Server] Fatal error: Please read "Security" section of the manual to find out how to run mysqld as root!
2019-10-20T18:44:13.780503Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
2019-10-20T18:44:13.780727Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/local/opt/mysql/bin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.18)  Homebrew.
2019-10-20T18:44:13.6NZ mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /usr/local/var/mysql/moriarty.farces.com.pid ended
```

Answer (score 23):

**Never use `sudo` with command `brew`**. It will ruin the ownership of related files. Running `brew` as root is not supported. (I'm talking about `brew`, not `mysqld`)

[Quote from Homebrew doc](https://docs.brew.sh/FAQ#why-does-homebrew-say-sudo-is-bad)

> tl;dr Sudo is dangerous, and you installed TextMate.app without sudo anyway.
>
> **Homebrew refuses to work using `sudo`.**

Warnings from the [source code of `brew`](https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/blob/85e4013989e849b374ff40858969be1125d63370/Library/Homebrew/brew.sh#L381-L398)

```rb
check-run-command-as-root() {
  ...
  odie <<EOS
Running Homebrew as root is extremely dangerous and no longer supported.
As Homebrew does not drop privileges on installation you would be giving all
build scripts full access to your system.
EOS
}
```

---

#### Solutions

1. Disable the service and remove the launchdaemon.

   ```sh
   # stop and unload the launchdaemon
   sudo launchctl unload -w /Library/LaunchDaemons/homebrew.mxcl.mysql.plist
   # remove the lauchdaemon file
   sudo rm -f /Library/LaunchDaemons/homebrew.mxcl.mysql.plist
   sudo rm -f /tmp/mysql.sock /tmp/mysqlx.sock
   ```
2. Fix ownership of homebrew related files

   ```sh
   # For x86 Mac
   sudo chown -R "$(whoami):admin" /usr/local/*
   # For M1 Mac
   sudo chown -R "$(whoami):admin" /opt/homebrew/*
   # it will take some time
   ```
3. Re-enable the MySQL service.

   ```sh
   # DO NOT USE "sudo brew"
   brew services start mysql
   ```

---

**Update**:

Seems some of you are not familiar with Homebrew. I'll explain how Homebrew manages services here.

`mysqld` listens at port `3306` by default, which is not a privileged port. So there's no need to start `mysqld` with root. `systemd` starts `mysqld` with root on Linux, but macOS is not Linux.

Homebrew manages services with the help of `launchd`, which is kind of a `systemd` alternative on macOS. `launchd` starts a foreground process and manages it for you, just like what `systemd` does.

`brew services start/stop mysql` will suffice your need. It creates a launchd file `~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.mysql.plist`, starts `mysqld` with it (run by current user).

`/usr/local/mysql/support-files/mysql.server` is a shell script brought by MySQL to help you start `mysqld`. Using it directly is not recommended **unless** you build MySQL from source **outside** Homebrew. If you're using Homebrew, just stick with `brew services`. Or say it in another way, if you're using Homebrew, you should do things in the Homebrew way.

Comment: Thanks for your interest. I followed your suggested "recipe" because it sounded like it made sense. I've been running home-brew for years as root, using sudo, without any problems (well I've had problems with each OS and most MySQL upgrades).

Comment: I'll never use `sudo` with `brew` again.
Thanks these steps helped me :D

Comment: There are a lot of tutorials all over the internet using brew with sudo, most people will copy and paste and believe blindly that those are from experts.

Comment: This saved me. It worked for me using mysql@5.7

Comment: Thanks so much. I had the problem before and I had to reinstall the MySQL. the same problem occurred and i found your solution. Thanks so much..

Comment: Thanks for the nice write-up. It just helped me solve the exact same problem (after many hours of trying). The path to my `.plist` file was actually slightly different to the one above and I had to run the command `sudo launchctl bootout` to stop it (rather than `sudo launchctl unload`). If you want to see all currently loaded jobs, running the command `launchctl list` is certainly a good idea. It helped me identify the exact name of the job I had to stop.

Answer (score 2):

MySQL refuses to start on Catalina because elevated privileges are required to run it.

You need to locate your MySQL `bin` directory first:

```
    which mysqld
```

*The result you get should be similar to* `/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql`.

The `support-files` directory contains the required scripts needed to start-up MySQL, and is located in the same directory where the `bin` directory is located. In the above example, the *support files* directory will be `/usr/local/mysql/support-files/`.

Start the MySQL service with administrative privileges as follows:

```
    sudo /usr/local/mysql/support-files/mysql.server start
```

**N.B:** In case the output from the first command you run is different from the one above, adjust the `support-files` directory accordingly as explained above.

Comment: Please take a look at the "Additional information" that I've added to my original question. Your pointing to Catalina requiring elevated privileges is perhaps helpful: All of the MySQL files live in /usr/local/cellar/mysql/8.0.18 with symlinks in /usr/local/bin

Comment: All I got when attempting this was: ERROR! The server quit without updating PID file

Answer (score 1):

Oh geez, he says, shaking his head...

This was a case of RTFM, and I didn't. Here's the [applicable page](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/changing-mysql-user.html) from the MySQL 8.0 Reference manual. And here's the magic juju:

Add `user=root` to the `[mysqld]` section of the `/usr/local/etc/my.cnf` file, like so:

```
# Default Homebrew MySQL server config
[mysqld]
# Only allow connections from localhost
bind-address = 127.0.0.1
mysqlx-bind-address = 127.0.0.1
user=root
```

Comment: Glad you find a solution. But I'm afraid you're going farther on the wrong track. **`brew` (not the `mysqld` daemon) is not supported being run as root.**, which could be confirm from the [source code of `brew`](https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/blob/85e4013989e849b374ff40858969be1125d63370/Library/Homebrew/brew.sh#L381-L398) and the [Homebrew documentation](https://docs.brew.sh/FAQ#why-does-homebrew-say-sudo-is-bad).

Answer (score -1):

I just encountered the same issue after upgrading to Catalina.
If I started MySQL server from system preferences it would just start and stop itself. The solution for me was:

sudo /usr/local/**mysql-8.0.17-macos10.14-x86_64**/support-files/mysql.server start

instead of: /usr/local/**mysql**/support-files/mysql.server start

I've encountered a lot of problems with Catalina. Now I can't start/stop mysql server from system preferences, only from terminal.

It's my first post so I hope this helps, I only registered to answer you since you're the only one I found with the same question.

Comment: I'm sorry, I guess I wasn't clear. I'm having problems getting MySQL 8.0.18 to run as a homebrew service on macOS 10.15 Catalina ("sudo brew services start mysql"). It runs (seemingly) fine with "mysql.server start."

Answer (score -1):

I solved like this:

Remove MySQL completely Watching: https://gist.github.com/vitorbritto/0555879fe4414d18569d

Install MySQL with Download do MySQL community server

https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/

And Done! Successfully!

Comment: My original question was about *homebrew* mysql.