# Can't start brew installed mysql after downgrading from 8.2 to 8.0.35

Tags: mysql, mysql-8.0

I decided to upgrade my brew version of mysql via:

```
brew install mysql
```

This installed 8.2 which I promptly found isn't compatible with Workbench. I removed it via:

```
brew uninstall mysql
```

I then installed the latest version of 8.0 using:

```
brew install mysql@8.0
```

I then restarted it to make sure it was running:

```
brew services restart mysql@8.0
```

I then tried to setup mysql using:

```
mysql_secure_installation
```

After entering my password I got the following error:

```
Error: Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)
```

There are various solutions proposed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5376427/cant-connect-to-local-mysql-server-through-socket-var-mysql-mysql-sock-38):

1. Use 127.0.0.1 - already have this in `my.cnf`
2. Add `socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock` to `my.cnf` - tried this and restarted to no avail
3. Try starting with `mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -P 3306 -u root -p` - didn't work

I then ran:

```
mysqld
```

Which got me the following output:

```
2023-12-14T23:37:41.322399Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /opt/homebrew/Cellar/mysql@8.0/8.0.35/bin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.35) starting as process 13478
2023-12-14T23:37:41.324735Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010159] [Server] Setting lower_case_table_names=2 because file system for /opt/homebrew/var/mysql/ is case insensitive
2023-12-14T23:37:41.329772Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
2023-12-14T23:38:00.170514Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-014061] [InnoDB] Invalid MySQL server downgrade: Cannot downgrade from 80200 to 80035. Downgrade is only permitted between patch releases.
mysqld: Can't open file: 'mysql.ibd' (errno: 0 - )
2023-12-14T23:38:00.226999Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-010334] [Server] Failed to initialize DD Storage Engine
2023-12-14T23:38:00.227083Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010020] [Server] Data Dictionary initialization failed.
2023-12-14T23:38:00.227093Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
2023-12-14T23:38:00.228201Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /opt/homebrew/Cellar/mysql@8.0/8.0.35/bin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.35)  Homebrew.
```

The bit that interested me was `Invalid MySQL server downgrade: Cannot downgrade from 80200 to 80035. Downgrade is only permitted between patch releases.`. This sounds like there's still an 8.2 version lurking somewhere and causing me issues. I've checked the homebrew folder and there definitely isn't another version in there though.

Any ideas where I could go from here? This stopping me from doing anything!!

I'm using a Mac with Sonoma 14.2.

Comment: sure it is compatible with workbencg

Comment: I was getting the same error as here https://www.reddit.com/r/mysql/comments/15dzgac/mysql_workbench_not_compatible_with_mysql_810/

Comment: it clearly states that it is only a warning, all works fine as long as 8.2 supports it. Workbench sends only the text to the server

Answer (score 1):

The following worked for me:

1 - Make sure original mysql files are removed:

```
brew uninstall mysql
brew cleanup
rm -rf /opt/homebrew/etc/my.cnf
rm -rf /opt/homebrew/var/mysql
```

2 - Install mysql 8.0

```
brew install mysql@8.0
```

3 - Disable the service and remove the launchdaemon and fix ownership of homebrew files [Source explaining this part] : ([Homebrew MySQL 8.0.18 on macOS 10.15 Catalina won't run as service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58466272/homebrew-mysql-8-0-18-on-macos-10-15-catalina-wont-run-as-service/58487534#58487534))

```
# stop and unload the launchdaemon    
sudo launchctl unload -w /Library/LaunchDaemons/homebrew.mxcl.mysql@8.0.plist
# remove the lauchdaemon file
sudo rm -f /Library/LaunchDaemons/homebrew.mxcl.mysql@8.0.plist
sudo rm -f /tmp/mysql.sock /tmp/mysqlx.sock
sudo chown -R "$(whoami):admin" /opt/homebrew/
```

Now start mysql should work:

```
brew services start mysql
```

Answer (score 0):

I went through this as well. When you install mysql with brew your DB data is stored in `/opt/homebrew/var/mysql/`. After installing a newer version, something gets set somewhere in that folder that prevents a future downgrade. So, after uninstalling all mysql versions with `brew uninstall`, I deleted the folder **along with my data**, which allowed me to then install mysql 8.0.36.