# MongoDB won't install on my mac. I installed homebrew in order to install Mongodb but I'm getting some error messages

Tags: mongodb, macos, homebrew

I used the following command to install mongodb:

```sh
my-MBP:~ user$ brew install mongodb:
```

and this was the output

```sh
Error: No available formula with the name "mongodb" 
==> Searching for a previously deleted formula (in the last month)...
Error: No previously deleted formula found.
==> Searching for similarly named formulae...
These similarly named formulae were found:
mongodb/brew/mongodb-community                 mongodb/brew/mongodb-community@3.4
mongodb/brew/mongodb-community-shell           mongodb/brew/mongodb-community@3.6
mongodb/brew/mongodb-community@3.2             mongodb/brew/mongodb-community@4.0
To install one of them, run (for example):
  brew install mongodb/brew/mongodb-community
==> Searching taps...
==> Searching taps on GitHub...
Error: No formulae found in taps.
```

This same thing happens why i try to enter "brew install mongo." Is homebrew not installed properly? How specifically can I resolve this issue?**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Installing MongoDB with Homebrew](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57856809/installing-mongodb-with-homebrew)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would follow the official installation guide, if you haven't already done so:
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-os-x/
https://github.com/mongodb/homebrew-brew

To install with brew, you must first:

```
brew tap mongodb/brew
```

Then,

```
brew install <mongodb>
```

For the input, `mongodb` doens't appear to be an option. It should be something like `mongodb-community@4.2` as shown in the guides.

Hope this helps!